# Team City Build configurations/ Build Steps using vscode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, build, teamcity

I found multiple extensions that manages, runs and run builds using vscode, but yet to find a way to be able to write custom scripts within vscode. That means I can choose the scripting language in Build Steps, write the code within vscode and run the build. Is there a way I am missing?

I had a look at :

https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-vscode-extension
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/visual-studio-addin.html

Comment: 1) Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are not the same - they are different tools with different purposes. 2) - _"That means I can choose the scripting language in Build Steps, write the code within vscode and run the build."_ - well, no, it doesn't. These extensions provide you an ability to interact with TC from the IDE/code editor, but the build configuration is still a separate entity. It can be stored in code but it has its own lifecycle - it is not just an engine that runs custom scripts.